# Command to find exact digit matching in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a dataset of fasta file which looks like this :

```
13_seq2344_ATCGACGGAACTGA
1342_seq2134_AGCTGTGGCAT
130_SEQ2289_TCGAATCGAGGAAC
```

I want to remove the line which contains "13" only

so My output should look like :

```
1342_seq2134_AGCTGTGGCAT
130_SEQ2289_TCGAATCGAGGAAC
```

I am trying `grep -w` , `grep -o`, `grep -E` all these are not working for me . `grep -o "13" filename`

do suggest any command that works .

Comment: What exactly have you tried with grep?

Comment: By 'the line which contains "13" only', do you mean lines start with '13_'? If so, `grep -v '^13_' fasta_file` should do the job.

Comment: grep -o "13" file name

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, if 1st field of your fasta file is NOT 13 then print that line. In `awk` program making field separator as `_` and checking if `$1`(first field) is NOT 13 then print that line.

```
awk -F'_' '$1!="13"' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file should not contain the number 13 anywhere in the string, you can match 13 without digits to the left and right and use `-v` to invert the match.

The `-P` is used for the lookarounds enabling a Perl-compatible regular expression.

```
grep -vP '(?<!\d)13(?!\d)' file
```

Or assert that the string does not contain 13 not being surrounded by digits:

```
grep -P '^(?!.*(?<!\d)13(?!\d))' file
```

Output

```
1342_seq2134_AGCTGTGGCAT
130_SEQ2289_TCGAATCGAGGAAC
```